# Health core drain rate -900%

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In RDR2 I am in Chapter 3. At health progression level 8, weight average, and temperature fair, I have the core drain rate of - 900%. By negative percentage I mean it is red and has a down arrow. **Why is it so? Is it a bug?**
As shown in the image the core and ring/bar are both full. The same for stamina and dead eye. The past 4 game-days, Arthur was just eating food in Valentine's saloon (5,6 portion per time ) and 5 to 11 hours of sleep in the hotel next to it. But weight does not go higher than average and the drain rate remains unchanged.

[image: core drain rate]

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by **poison**. E.g: If you got bit by a snake, you'll have this core drain rate until you cure yourself.

Here's how to do it:

Get a **Potent Health Cure**, which can be bought in shops or crafted on your campfire with 1x Ginseng and 1x Yarrow. The recipe is available from the beginning of the game, so you should have it.

Drink the health cure, eat well and soon you'll be cured.

Also, **cold** and **weight** can cause an **elevated core drain rate**, but not at those levels.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact problem. Not poison not overheated not over weight. I believe it's a bug. I saved the game and reloaded. The drain rate went back down to normal.